# Does firestore realtime onsnapshot listener created in javascript detach itself if we refresh the browser window?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, listener, snapshot

If i create a firestore realtime snapshot listener in my javascript file. Will it be detached itself if that browser window is refreshed ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a browser window is reloaded (which is essentially the same as closing and opening again), then the entire page loads fresh.  All previous data on that page (including database listeners) are automatically destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for this very quick answer sir, But please i have been though many articles related to this query on internet but didn't found answer with full surety. Please don't mind, Can i be sure for my question according to your answer?  @Doug Stevenson

Comment: Do we have any callback there to check if listener is removed successfully ?

Comment: There is no way to check.  You have to trust that the browser stops everything on the page that is no longer loaded.